# xgboost binary logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

I am having problems running logistic regression with xgboost that can be summarized on the following example.

Lets assume I have a very simple dataframe with two predictors and one target variable:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'X1' : pd.Series([1,0,0,1]), 'X2' : pd.Series([0,1,1,0]), 'Y' : pd.Series([0,1,1,0], )})
```

[image]

we can clearly see that when X1 =1 and X2=0, Y is 0 and when X1=0 and X2=1, Y is 1.

My idea is to build a model that outputs the probability that an observation belongs to each one of the classes, so if I run xgboost trying to predict two new observations (1,0) and (0,1) like so:

```
X = df[['X1','X2']].values            
y = df['Y'].values

params  = {'objective': 'binary:logistic',
          'num_class': 2
          } 

clf1 = xgb.train(params=params, dtrain=xgb.DMatrix(X, y), num_boost_round=100)                    
clf1.predict(xgb.DMatrix(test.values))
```

the output is:

```
array([[ 0.5,  0.5],
       [ 0.5,  0.5]], dtype=float32)
```

which, I imagine, means that for the first observation, there is 50% chance it belonging to each one of the classes.

I'd like to know why wont the algorithm output a proper (1,0) or something closer to that if the relationship between the variables is clear.

FYI, I did try with more data (Im only using 4 rows for simplicity) and the behavior is almost the same; what I do notice is that, not only the probabilities do not sum to 1, they are often very small like so:

```
array([[ 0.00356463,  0.00277259],
       [ 0.00315137,  0.00268578],
       [ 0.00453343,  0.00157113],
```

Comment: I think the output of the xgboost is log-odds ratio, not probability.

Comment: The coefficient in xgboost can't be really interpreted. Use the created model to predict your training data. You should get a probability.

Comment: what sense does it make to predict the train data? I want to predict the test data.

Comment: To get back a probability an no more log-odds.

Comment: sorry, I dont get what you mean, for each observation of the test data, I want the probability of it belonging to each one of the classes, 0 and 1. The model is outputting 0.5, which you say is the log-odds ratio. how can I transform it to probability? 
Thanks for your help

Comment: No, the sum of the coefficient of the tree are the log-odds ratio(if I remember it well). Here, your result is quite strange, but your training data as well,as your variable x2 is the same as your label. Try to do it again with a little bit of noise.